# How to fix issue sending text to Arduino over bluetooth serial port from C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I have an Arduino Uno with a Bluesmirf Silver module connected. My Arduino has a temperature sensor which records the temp regularly. The Arduino listens for any string being sent to it over bluetooth and responds with the latest data.

I have written a C# application to fetch this data but I am seeing some strange behaviour. I am using the following code to connect, send a string and get the returned data.

```
mPort = new SerialPort(mPortName, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
mPort.Open();
mPort.Write("download");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
while (mPort.BytesToRead > 0)
{
  String data = mPort.ReadExisting();
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action<String>(AddMessage), data);
}
```

The data I get back looks like this:

Line added locally within C# application:

```
Send: download
```

Lines added based on data received from Arduino:

```
Read: d???+?
GotData
------
Total Readings, 1069
Num Readings, 360
Lost Readings, 709
Reading Interval, 240000
------
350,19.34
351,19.34
352,19.34
353,20.31
....
```

All the text looks fine apart from the string which is being echoed back which I sent to the Arduino. Have I done something wrong with the way I sent the data?

FYI - The datasheet for the bluetooth module is here: http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-bluetooth-um.pdf

@Jeff - This is the code which I use on my Arduino to receive data: https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino/blob/master/tempsensor/StringReader.cpp

@Jeff - stringDataLen defines the length and I call the overall function from this file: https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino/blob/master/tempsensor/tempsensor.ino

EDIT: Here is the complete source code

- Arduino - https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino/tree/master/tempsensor
- C# application - https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino/tree/master/serialdownload

The C# code is definitely getting the flow control wrong for some reason. I have switched to use the following code in C# and this gets a string through without corruption.

```
private void write(SerialPort mPort, string str)
{
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        mPort.Write(new char[] {c}, 0, 1);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant Arduino code? Is it programmed to echo the characters it receives?

Comment: I think you are corrupting variables because you have not declared the length of stringData in StringReader.cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by me using the SoftwareSerial class to communicate with my Bluetooth module on pins 2 & 3. I was using a baud rate of 115200 which is claimed to be supported on this page: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

However, this page ( http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialBegin ) states that the maximum baud rate supported is actually 9600. I'm not sure whether this is accurate but reducing my baud rate to 9600 has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

An incorrect encoding perhaps?

```
mPort = new SerialPort(mPortName, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
mPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;   // Or System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
mPort.Open();
mPort.Write("download");
```

Read byte-by-byte and check each byte one by one to debug lower level problems. `ReadExisting()` converts bytes to a `String` based on the `Encoding` property.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to decrease communication speed, because there is no reason to use 115200bps (only if your module demand this speed, then it's ok). Also you are sending string "download" which is not good, rather use markers something like "#D" which internally for your Arduino device means, send data to computer. In this way you are sending only two bytes instead eight, and you will decrease probability of error, and Arduino code will be better.

Now, let's try fix the problem. First try use something like this when you are reading data from Arduino device:

```
ArayList dataReceaved=new ArrayList():
while(serialPort.BytesToRead>0 && serialPort.IsOpen){
                dataReceaved.Add(serialPort.ReadByte());
            }
```

So I suggest you to read byte by byte, in this or similar way. Also you shold be careful if you are sending numbers from Arduino device. If you are, then use something like this:

```
Serial.print(temperatureValue,BYTE);
```

With this code you explicitly say that data you are sending is byte long. If this not help, please let me know, so we can try something else.

Comment: I disagree with the comments about 115200 and worrying about shorter packets to decrease errors.  115200 is plenty slow, and you are not going to have bit errors unless you are trying to connect over a 20 foot long cable.

Comment: he is connecting with bluetooth so grater distances are possible.

Comment: But the Bluetooth link runs over SPP/RFCOMM, which is a reliable transport, wireless errors are hidden by retransmission.

Comment: Suggesting I send at a lower speed or send shorter strings doesn't actually solve my problem - it only works around it.

Comment: I said to you, read byte by byte, don't use read existing. I had 3 projects and it worked great.

Comment: The issue isn't about how I read data sent by the Arduino. The issue is how I correctly send data to the Arduino. This only works for me if I do it byte by byte with 10ms between bytes. This seems extremely wrong.